# Making my jQuery more re-usable

Tags: jquery, function

I have the following jQuery code in my website for sorting out the vertical rhythm of my wordpress site:

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){
        $(".wp-caption").each(function() {
                /* variables */
                var this_img   = $(this);
                var baseline   = 24;
                var img_height = this_img.outerHeight();
            /* do the maths */
            var remainder  = parseFloat(img_height%baseline);

            /* how much do we need to add? */
            var offset     = parseFloat(baseline-remainder);

            var top_offset = Math.round(offset/2);
            var bottom_offset = offset - top_offset;

            /* apply the margin to the image */
            this_img.css("margin-bottom",bottom_offset+"px");
            this_img.css("margin-top",top_offset+"px");
        });
});
```

I would like to make this more re-usable, so that rather than stuffing all of the code in the `.bind` I can do something like `$(".wp-caption").verticalRhythm(24)`. I'm not sure if this means I need a plugin and if so, what exactly that means.

Any ideas and help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's something like a plugin. Here's basically what it would look like:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.verticalRhythm = function(baseline) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var this_img   = $(this);
        var img_height = this_img.outerHeight();
        /* do the maths */
        var remainder  = parseFloat(img_height%baseline);

        /* how much do we need to add? */
        var offset     = parseFloat(baseline-remainder);

        var top_offset = Math.round(offset/2);
        var bottom_offset = offset - top_offset;

        /* apply the margin to the image */
        // this_img.css("margin-bottom",bottom_offset+"px");
        // this_img.css("margin-top",top_offset+"px");
        // jQuery will add pixels to css values. And you add them all at once.
        this_img.css({ marginTop: top_offset, marginBottom: bottom_offset });
    });
};

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: When comparing this to @PHPglue 's answer, there are a number of differences - what is the wrapping `(function($){` and `})(jQuery)` about?

Comment: It's called a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). It encapsulates all the code while also making sure that `$` is equal to `jQuery`, even if the user is using `jQuery.noConflict`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$.fn.extend({
  verticalRhythm : function(baseline){
    $(window).bind('load', function(){
      $(this).each(function(){
        var this_img = $(this), img_height = this_img.outerHeight();
        var remainder = parseFloat(img_height%baseline);
        var offset = parseFloat(baseline-remainder);
        var top_offset = Math.round(offset/2);
        var bottom_offset = offset - top_offset;
        this_img.css("margin-bottom",bottom_offset+"px");
        this_img.css("margin-top",top_offset+"px");
      });
    });
  }
});
```